# What's the difference between each version of flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flashlite

According to [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/index.html) there's flex **1,2,3,4**,what's the main difference between them?

Is there a version of flex that supports `flash lite 2` which my project is using?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flex#Versions

So far as I know, no version of Flex are supported on Flash Lite.  However, it may be possible to run a Flex 1 / 1.5 app on Flex Lite since they are ActionScript 2 based.  But, Flex 1/1.5 had a very different licensing, pricing, and development model than Flex 2 and later.  I'm not sure I'd want to do anything that predates Flex 2.

Your best bet is to not use Flex, but rather investigate building this app with Flash Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Lite 2 is not supported by any version of Flex.

Comment: @James Ward  In theory, Flex 1 / 1.5 are ActionScript 2 and should run in Flash Lite, right?  I can easily envision performance issues, attempting that though.

Comment: Yeah.  Performance would be the primary issue if it actually worked.

Comment: Can you talk about the pricing and licensing of Flex 3?Is it true that I won't be able to build a flex 3 application without a license?

Comment: The Flex SDK has been free and open source since Flex 2 (and still is today).  It's just the IDE that costs you money.

Comment: With the exception of the Data Vis swc... which was tied to the IDE until recently...

Comment: Correct.  The Data Viz stuff was a feature of Flex Builder (commercial).  But now it's part of the free Flex 4 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As James mentioned corrrectly, no version of Flex supports Flash Light 2.